# How to check if a Goal with specific ID has been ever registered for the contact?

Tags: xdb, goals

I need to know if the goal was ever registered on the contact in its any visit on any interaction. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Slow approach

You could load all previous visits using this code:

```
IEnumerable<IInteractionData> visits = Tracker.Current.Contact.LoadHistorycalData(visitsToLoad);
```

Then you could check every page of every visit and see if the goal was triggered. This would not perform well though.

### Fast approach

You should use the [**Key Behavior Cache**](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/digital_marketing/personalization/historical_personalization/key_behavior_cache) which contains (a configurable amount of) goals, events, campaigns etc. that have been triggered by contacts, even in previous visits.

```
Guid goalId = // your goal ID
KeyBehaviorCache cache = Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Contact.GetKeyBehaviorCache();
bool goalTriggered = cache.Goals.Any(_ => _.Id == goalId);
```

Keep in mind that the Key Behavior Cache contains a limited number of entries. So you should make sure it's tuned for your needs. See this documentation page for more information:

[**The Key Behavior Cache settings, pipelines, and methods**](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/digital_marketing/personalization/historical_personalization/the_key_behavior_cache_settings_pipelines_and_methods)

Comment: Super! the KeyBehaviorCache variant will work fine for my purposes. Thanks.